# Finding directories that contains given files?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, find, command

I hope this  is an interesting question.. I want to find a directory that contains all the given files ..  Until now what I have done is as follows

Find multiple files in unix...

```
find . -type f \( -name "*cache" -o -name "*xml" -o -name "*html" \)
```

reference : http://alvinalexander.com/linux-unix/linux-find-multiple-filenames-patterns-command-example

Finding only directories containing given files...

```
find . -type f -name '*.pdf' |sed 's#\(.*\)/.*#\1#' |sort -u
```

Reference : http://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/107488-find-files-display-only-directory-list-containing-those-files.html

How can I make a command that will give me a directory which contains all the given files... ( The files must be in given directory only not in sub directory .. and all the files given in a list must be present )

Want to search for WordPress theme directories

Comment: Where is the list of files you are trying to find?

Comment: index.php style.css page.php single.php comment.php basic files required for wordpress by a wordpress theme. My goal is to find all wordpress themes present in a given linux system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `find` like this:

```
find -type d -exec sh -c '[ -f "$0"/index.php ] && [ -f "$0"/style.css ]' '{}' \; -print
```

To search for more files, simply add them like `&& [ -f "$0"/other_file ]`. The return code of `sh` will indicate whether all the files could be found. The name of the directory will only be printed if `sh` has exited successfully, i.e. when all the files have been found.

Testing it out:

```
$ mkdir dir1
$ touch dir1/a
$ mkdir dir2
$ touch dir2/a
$ touch dir2/b
$ find -type d -exec sh -c '[ -f "$0"/a ] && [ -f "$0"/b ]' '{}' \; -print
./dir2
```

Here I've created two directories, `dir1` and `dir2`. `dir2` contains both files, so its name is printed.

As gniourf_gniourf has mentioned in the comments (thanks), it is not necessary to use `sh` to do this. Instead, you can do this:

```
find -type d -exec test -f '{}'/a -a -f '{}'/b \; -print
```

`[` and `test` do the same thing. This approach uses `-a` instead of `&&` to combine multiple separate tests, which reduces the number of processes being executed.

In response to your comment, you can add all of the directories found to an archive like this:

```
find -type d -exec test -f '{}'/a -a -f '{}'/b \; -print0 | tar --null -T - -cf archive.tar.bz2
```

The `-print0` option prints the names of each of the directories, separated by a null byte. This is useful as it prevents problems with files containing spaces in their names. The names are read by `tar` and added to the bzip-compressed archive. Note that some versions of `find` do not support the `-print0` option. If your version doesn't support it, you may be able to use `-print` (and remove the `--null` option to `tar`), depending on your directory names.

Comment: How do i compress all the directories that we get as the output of the above command  ??? I mean adding all the directories to a archive at once...

Comment: Unable to unpack the archive getting error like archive.tar.bz2 is not look like a tar file.  <br/>   bzip2 -cd archive.tar.bz2 | tar xvf -      <br/> bzip2 -d archive.tar.bz2     <br/>     tar xvjf archive.tar.bz2      <br/>     tar jfx archive.tar.bz2    and also how to  run the command through PHP exec() function ??    I need to store the directories in an array in PHP . Thank you in Advance :)

Comment: @vivek the command in my answer creates a bzip-compressed archive already. To decompress it you can use `tar -jxf archive.tar.bz2`. If you have any further questions, I think that you should ask them separately, as this one is in danger of becoming too broad.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# list of files to be found
arr=(index.php style.css page.php single.php comment.php)
# length of the array
len="${#arr[@]}"

# cd to top level themes directory
cd themes

# search for listed files in all the subdirectories from current path
while IFS= read -d '' -r dir; do
   [[ $(ls "${arr[@]/#/$dir/}" 2>/dev/null | wc -l) -eq $len ]] && echo "$dir"
done < <(find . -type d -print0)
```

Comment: It is working fine and giving expected output. Thanks for your time sir. It works fine when i run it through command line but it is giving error like "syntax error near unexpected token `<' on line number 11. Rest everything is fine. Thank you sir...

Comment: Both the answers are correct but I am not able to accept them. It just keeps toggling between them.

Comment: Yes you cannot mark both answers as accepted. Only the one that works best for you will be marked.

Comment: Can you explain the script?