# Searching for directories that contain two files of any name, with specific extensions

Tags: shell, unix, find, command

I found this post that does what I am looking to do but the original poster knew what files they were searching for.

[Finding directories that contains given files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28363569/finding-directories-that-contains-given-files)

How would I update this find command to search for and list any sub directories that contain two files of any name but have two specific file extensions?

```
find -type d -exec sh -c '[ -f "$0"/index.php ] && [ -f "$0"/style.css ]' '{}' \; -print
```

Specifically I am looking to search all the subfolders for directories that contain a *.RAR file **AND** a *.VMK file.  When I replace the "index.php" and "style.css" with the specific filenames of a known folder, I get the proper result.

Now I just need some help in replacing those specific filenames with the wildcard and extension.

I've tried these two options and they do not work as hoped.

```
find -type f '[ -f "$0"/*.rar ] && [ -f "$0"/*.vmk ]' '{}' \

find -type f '[ -f "$0"/"*.rar" ] && [ -f "$0"/"*.vmk" ]' '{}' \
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance, as it is much appreciated! :)

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *two options* you tried differ significantly from the original working command. If you just replace `index.php` and `style.css` therein with your desired `*.rar` and `*.vmk` (without `""`), respectively, it will work as long as there aren't more `*.rar` or `*.vmk` files in a folder.

Comment: Ugh. I made a COPY & PASTE error in my original post and posted one of my failed code attempts.

However, when I apply your comments Armali to what I meant to post, it worked as desired.

Here is what I ended up with:

 (   find -type d -exec sh -c '[ -f "$0"/*.rar ] && [ -f "$0"/*.mkv ]' '{}' \; -print  )

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ugh. I made a COPY & PASTE error in my original post and posted one of my failed code attempts.

However, when I apply your comments Armali to what I meant to post, it worked as desired.

Here is what I ended up with:

```
find -type d -exec sh -c '[ -f "$0"/*.rar ] && [ -f "$0"/*.mkv ]' '{}' \; -print
```

Thank you.